# Configurar Extencion Live Server de VS Code

Tags: vscode

Buen día, mi duda es como configurar la extencion de VS Code Live Server para correr en otros navegadores, sin la necesidad de cambiar el que esta por defecto en el sistema operativo.

Solo para hacer la prueba cambie el navegador por defecto de mi sistema operativo (Windows 10) yo el que tenia era Chrome y Live Server corria con Chrome, despues cambie a Firefox Developer, recargue el VS Code y Live Server corrio con Firefox Developer (Obviamente esto quiere decir que toma el navegador de nuestro equipo que esta por defecto).

Comento nuevamente que lo que me gustaría, es poder cambiar el navegador con el que corre el Live Server, sin afecta o cambiar el navegador por defecto de mi sistema operativo.

Si alguien sabe le agradeciera su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a File/Preferences/Settings/Extensions/Live Server Config y modifica el parámetro Settings: Custom Browser. Elige entre los elementos de la lista de navegadores el que quieres que quede por defecto.
Un saludo

Comment: Un poco tarde la respuesta pero funciona gracias.